# Element ID from document.getElementsByClassName

Tags: javascript, html, getelementsbyclassname

Relatively new to JS/Ajax, so I may be missing something obvious here. Let's say at some point in javascript I run ajax to get a number of div elements with a certain class name. I then want to retrieve the html id tag from each of these elements and do something with that information (say populate the element), something like so.

```
var divstopop = document.getElementsByClassName("popField"),x;
    for(x in divstopop){

    divstopop[x].innerHTML= x.id; //x.id or something?
}
```

Is this in any way possible to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `in` is not how you should iterate over an array of elements. You should use the `.length` property and use numeric indexing:

```js
for (var i = 0; i < divstopop.length; ++i) {
    // Get id property from element and set as innerHTML
    divstopop[i].innerHTML = divstopop[i].id;
}
```

With the introduction of ES6, you can also use [`for ... of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) to accomplish what you want:

```js
for (const node of document.getElementsByClassName("popField")) {
  node.innerHTML = node.id;
}
```

Comment: `innerHTML` should be id of the div. Use `divstopop[i].id`

Comment: Also, I'm not sure if '.id' is the right syntax for this, I just made that up to get my point across of what I'd like to do

Comment: `.id` is right: jsfiddle.net/tsRJJ/ and you have to know index of that particular element of which you wanna get the ID.

Comment: a `for (... of ...)` loop is also ok in this case.